# Fiori SAPUI5 - App does not work after deployment

Tags: deployment, sapui5, sap-fiori, sap-web-ide

I am developing an SAPUI5 fiori application in the Web IDE (cloud platform).

In the development environment everything works fine. But when I deploy the app on the ABAP Respository and start it in the launchpad, it does not work, because the style.css file is not found.

I took a closer look to the url of the **style.css** and I realized, that it has a different structure than another app that I have deployed months ago.

This file is not found:

```
https://mycompany/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/ui2/ushell/resources/~20181114160800~/M_C/FurnitureContract/css/style.css
```

In this Link above, the namespace of my application is included in the URL: `M_C/FurnitureContract`

This file is found in another app that works:

```
https://mycompany/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/moeb_change/~68ABCE58F96887C38EE8B5139A5D5A5E~5/css/style.css
```

In the link above, the namespace of the application is not included in the URL.

My structure looks like this:

[image]

So far I have analysed the other files of my application and they have the following URL structure:

```
https://mycompany/sap/bc/ui5_ui5/sap/z_moeb/~4E052E59AEEA69D8B40B84C6C43A9CC1~C/component.js
```

This is the correct URL, but now why is the URL of my css-file different? When I replace the `/component.js` with `/css/style.css` and call this URL in the browser, then I get the css file.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: How is your style file referenced?

Comment: @Marc Its referenced in the manifest.json file like this: 

`"resources": {
    "css": [
     {
        "uri": "css/style.css"
     }
 ]
},`